# Instance Failure Exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

It was working still yesterday but now it is not working because sqlexpress service is stopped and it is not starting. I have connection string:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files\Setup1\DB.mdf;
Integrated Security=True;
Connect Timeout=30;
User Instance=True
```

When I open this connection it throws exception `Instance Failure`. This is my WPF application and I am using .NET Framework 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just stopped mssqlserver service and started sqlexpress service then sqlexpress service get started..now problem is that mssqlserver and sqlexpress both services cannot start simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

```
@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files\Setup1\DB.mdf;
Integrated Security=True;
Connect Timeout=30;
User Instance=True";
```

Make sure your SQL Server instance(MSSQLSERVER) is running.

To do this,

(i)Open run dialog box and type

(ii)"services.msc" (without quotes) and hit Enter.

(ii)In Service Management Console you can check whether it is running or not.

Or

Try Deleting the folder  C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data   also restart VS after deleting the folder.

Comment: my conn str was working even though mssqlserver service was stopped it only needs sqlexpress service..but now my mssqlserver service is running and sqlexpress is stopped and it not starting

Comment: Check the modified answer

Comment: are you sure connection string is mentioned as above, i dont see any problems with your connection string

Comment: yeah i am sure my conn str is correct because it was working. problem is sqlexpress service is not starting